# What is the meaning of "the same - than"?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

I'm working as a Software Engineer in US, and I'm a non-native speaker. I am familiar with the phrase "same as".

When I read the following wiki page, I encountered a phrase consisting of "same" and "than". I am copying and pasting that sentence at the bottom of this question.

I do not clearly understand what it means. Could anyone please tell me whether the following sentence makes sense? If so, could you explain to me what it means?

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_function:

> In object-oriented programming, a friend function, that is a "friend" of a given class, is a function that is given the **same** access **than** methods to private and protected data.

Comment: A grammatical error was introduced by the latest person to edit that page.

Comment: That's typically an error a French person can make as in French (and Spanish I think), comparisons use the same adverb: "un accès *plus* étendu *que*, un accès *moins* étendu *que*, le *même* accès *que*" (extended/lesser/identical access). The last *que* can be erroneously translated in *than*. Whois tool indicates the initial author used a computer at UCSC, so it's difficult to confirm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a mistake.

> *The same* is followed by *as*. It is not followed by *that* or *than*:

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/same-similar-identical

Answer (score 2):

There is a good explanation for this on the forum:

http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/same-than-same-as-same-that.400069/

In comparatives, when one is 'more' than the other you use '**than': bigger than, smaller than, colder than, warmer than, more interesting than, less interesting than.**

When they are the same you always use 'as'. This is the same **as** this.

If you use another adjective you put the adjective between two 'as':

My house is **as** big **as** yours.

John is **as** tall **as** Pete, but Nick is taller **than** them.

So the sentence should be:

> In object-oriented programming, a friend function, that is a
>   "friend" of a given class, is a function that is given the **same**
>   access **as** methods to private and protected data.